# MySQL dies at same time by night

Tags: mysql-5.5

my MySQL Database dies every night at around 11p.m. and I have absolutly no idea whats the problem.

Maybe you can help me:

The error.log says:

```
160412 11:37:13 [Warning] IP address '123.158.49.205' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
160412 11:37:14 [Warning] IP address '124.90.52.228' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
21:03:21 UTC - mysqld got signal 11 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed, 
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.
key_buffer_size=16777216
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=13
max_threads=151
thread_count=8
connection_count=8
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 346701 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.
Thread pointer: 0x55f5c57507f0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 7fad00a16e98 thread_stack 0x30000
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x20)[0x55f5c36f06b0]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x3d5)[0x55f5c35da1c5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x10340)[0x7fad15e74340]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x5efb8e)[0x55f5c37edb8e]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x5dfd5a)[0x55f5c37ddd5a]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x5e3538)[0x55f5c37e1538]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x5e37da)[0x55f5c37e17da]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x551699)[0x55f5c374f699]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x5530b4)[0x55f5c37510b4]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x55b9d5)[0x55f5c37599d5]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x5b3ad6)[0x55f5c37b1ad6]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x5b6654)[0x55f5c37b4654]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x559812)[0x55f5c3757812]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x51bd2b)[0x55f5c3719d2b]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x523dba)[0x55f5c3721dba]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x52705b)[0x55f5c372505b]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x514888)[0x55f5c3712888]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x5033de)[0x55f5c37013de]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN7handler13ha_update_rowEPKhPh+0x55)[0x55f5c35e0b85]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z12mysql_updateP3THDP10TABLE_LISTR4ListI4ItemES6_PS4_jP8st_ordery15enum_duplicatesbPySB_+0x10a8)[0x55f5c35629f8]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z21mysql_execute_commandP3THD+0x383e)[0x55f5c34f7bce]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z11mysql_parseP3THDPcjP12Parser_state+0x160)[0x55f5c34fb0c0]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z16dispatch_command19enum_server_commandP3THDPcj+0x1df2)[0x55f5c34fd652]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z24do_handle_one_connectionP3THD+0x176)[0x55f5c358a3d6]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_one_connection+0x41)[0x55f5c358a431]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x8182)[0x7fad15e6c182]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7fad1558f47d]

Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Query (7facd4004aa0): is an invalid pointer
Connection ID (thread ID): 6936
Status: NOT_KILLED

The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
160412 23:03:21 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
160412 23:03:21 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
160412 23:03:21 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
160412 23:03:21 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
160412 23:03:21 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
160412 23:03:21 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
160412 23:03:21 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
160412 23:03:21 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
160412 23:03:21 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 104927088343
160412 23:03:21  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 104927186055
InnoDB: 1 transaction(s) which must be rolled back or cleaned up
InnoDB: in total 556 row operations to undo
InnoDB: Trx id counter is CBC200
160412 23:03:21  InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...
InnoDB: Progress in percents: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 
InnoDB: Apply batch completed
160412 23:03:21  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
InnoDB: Starting in background the rollback of uncommitted transactions
160412 23:03:21  InnoDB: Rolling back trx with id CBC067, 556 rows to undo

InnoDB: Rolling back of trx id CBC067 completed
160412 23:03:22  InnoDB: Rollback of non-prepared transactions completed
160412 23:03:22 InnoDB: 5.5.47 started; log sequence number 104927186055
160412 23:03:22 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306
160412 23:03:22 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
160412 23:03:22 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
160412 23:03:22 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
160412 23:03:22 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.47-0ubuntu0.14.04.1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu)
21:03:30 UTC - mysqld got signal 11 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed, 
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

key_buffer_size=16777216
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=2
max_threads=151
thread_count=1
connection_count=1
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 346701 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x55a1c7d8ad70
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 7fee24691e98 thread_stack 0x30000
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x20)[0x55a1c5b276b0]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x3d5)[0x55a1c5a111c5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x10340)[0x7fee3996b340]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x5efb8e)[0x55a1c5c24b8e]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x5dfd5a)[0x55a1c5c14d5a]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x5e3538)[0x55a1c5c18538]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x5e37da)[0x55a1c5c187da]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x551699)[0x55a1c5b86699]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x5530b4)[0x55a1c5b880b4]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x55b9d5)[0x55a1c5b909d5]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x5b3ad6)[0x55a1c5be8ad6]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x5b6654)[0x55a1c5beb654]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x559812)[0x55a1c5b8e812]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x51bd2b)[0x55a1c5b50d2b]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x523dba)[0x55a1c5b58dba]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x52705b)[0x55a1c5b5c05b]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x514888)[0x55a1c5b49888]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x5033de)[0x55a1c5b383de]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN7handler13ha_update_rowEPKhPh+0x55)[0x55a1c5a17b85]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z12mysql_updateP3THDP10TABLE_LISTR4ListI4ItemES6_PS4_jP8st_ordery15enum_duplicatesbPySB_+0x10a8)[0x55a1c59999f8]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z21mysql_execute_commandP3THD+0x383e)[0x55a1c592ebce]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z11mysql_parseP3THDPcjP12Parser_state+0x160)[0x55a1c59320c0]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z16dispatch_command19enum_server_commandP3THDPcj+0x1df2)[0x55a1c5934652]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z24do_handle_one_connectionP3THD+0x176)[0x55a1c59c13d6]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_one_connection+0x41)[0x55a1c59c1431]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x8182)[0x7fee39963182]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7fee3908647d]

Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Query (7fee083727c0): is an invalid pointer
Connection ID (thread ID): 37
Status: NOT_KILLED

The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
160412 23:03:30 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
160412 23:03:30 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
160412 23:03:30 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
160412 23:03:30 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
160412 23:03:30 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
160412 23:03:30 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
160412 23:03:30 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
160412 23:03:30 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
160412 23:03:30 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 104927088343
160412 23:03:30  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 104927416563
InnoDB: 1 transaction(s) which must be rolled back or cleaned up
InnoDB: in total 1014 row operations to undo
InnoDB: Trx id counter is CBC400
160412 23:03:30  InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...
InnoDB: Progress in percents: 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 
InnoDB: Apply batch completed
InnoDB: Starting in background the rollback of uncommitted transactions
160412 23:03:31  InnoDB: Rolling back trx with id CBC202, 1014 rows to undo

InnoDB: Progress in percents: 1160412 23:03:31  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100
InnoDB: Rolling back of trx id CBC202 completed
160412 23:03:31  InnoDB: Rollback of non-prepared transactions completed
160412 23:03:32 InnoDB: 5.5.47 started; log sequence number 104927416563
160412 23:03:32 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306
160412 23:03:32 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
160412 23:03:32 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
160412 23:03:32 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
160412 23:03:32 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.47-0ubuntu0.14.04.1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu)
```

my.cnf:

```
#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
# 
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

# This will be passed to all mysql clients
# It has been reported that passwords should be enclosed with ticks/quotes
# escpecially if they contain "#" chars...
# Remember to edit /etc/mysql/debian.cnf when changing the socket location.
[client]
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# Here is entries for some specific programs
# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram

# This was formally known as [safe_mysqld]. Both versions are currently parsed.
[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0

[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
innodb_lock_wait_timeout=280
wait_timeout=57600
net_read_timeout=240
net_write_timeout=240
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
#bind-address       = localhost
#
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer      = 16M
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
#max_connections        = 100
#table_cache            = 64
#thread_concurrency     = 10
#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_limit   = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M
#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
#general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log             = 1
#
# Error log - should be very few entries.
#
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
#
# Here you can see queries with especially long duration
#log_slow_queries   = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
#long_query_time = 2
#log-queries-not-using-indexes
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
#server-id      = 1
#log_bin            = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M
#binlog_do_db       = include_database_name
#binlog_ignore_db   = include_database_name
#
# * InnoDB
#
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
#
# * Security Features
#
# Read the manual, too, if you want chroot!
# chroot = /var/lib/mysql/
#
# For generating SSL certificates I recommend the OpenSSL GUI "tinyca".
#
# ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem
# ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
# ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem



[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet  = 16M

[mysql]
#no-auto-rehash # faster start of mysql but no tab completition

[isamchk]
key_buffer      = 16M

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

Let my know if you some more information

Greets dan

Answer (score 1):

based on the log file there is a transaction run that consume all of the memory, if you want to stop the crash you need either:

1. increase memory for MySQL. at least by double memory  value to test if the new memory that reserved to MySQL is enough.
2. reformat the transaction to take less memory.